# How to draw some cumulative incidence plots in trellis/faceted style in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to create a trellis/faceted plot to see the cumulative incidence of several groups in my data. So I started with

```
library(rms)
library(dplyr)

data(colon)
fit1 <- npsurv(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = colon %>% filter(rx=="Obs"))
survplot(fit1, fun = function(x) 1-x)
fit2 <- npsurv(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = colon %>% filter(rx=="Lev"))
survplot(fit2, fun = function(x) 1-x)
fit3 <- npsurv(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = colon %>% filter(rx=="Lev+5FU"))
survplot(fit3, fun = function(x) 1-x)
```

Then I get stuck to put the three plots together and show the name of group on top each plot. I don't like the `mfrow` or `mfcol` solution. Can someone explain how to use `lattice` or `ggplot2` to do this?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org) approach - using `purrr::map` and `purrr:map_df` to fit the model for every level of `rx`. The `1 - x` part is left as an excercise to the reader. The only 'magic' part is using `mget` to subset the list-like result of `npsurv` to get only the columns needed for the plot.

```
library(rms)
library(tidyverse)
data(colon)

colon %>%
  split(.$rx) %>%
  map(~ npsurv(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = .)) %>%
  map_df(~ mget(c("surv", "upper", "lower", "time"), 
                as.environment(.)) %>%
           data.frame, 
         .id = "rx") %>%
  ggplot(aes(time)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), fill = "gray80") +
  geom_line(aes(y = surv)) +
  facet_wrap(~ rx)
```

[image: Survival as a trellis plot]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. Here is my solution

```
require(rms)
require(dplyr)
data(colon)
dat <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(colon$rx))) {
    j = sort(unique(colon$rx))[i]
    fit <- npsurv(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = colon%>%filter(rx == j))
    dat[[i]] <- data.frame(Time = fit$time,
                            Probability = 1 - fit$surv,
                            Group = c(rep("Male", fit$strata[1]), rep("Female", fit$strata[2])),
                            Center = j)
}
data_all <- do.call(rbind, dat)
data_all$Group <- factor(data_all$Group, levels = c("Male", "Female"))

require(lattice)
p <- xyplot(Probability ~ Time| Center, group = Group, data = data_all, 
            grid = T, type = "l", 
            auto.key = list("top", lines = T, points = F),
            par.settings = list(lwd = 2))
p
```